Python function causes changes to input pandas dataframe
I have a Python function that modifies a pandas dataframe in various ways. This includes dropping a column. Counter to my intuition, this drop operation is not limited to the environment (if that's the right word) of the function, but passes out to the main coding environment, dropping the column in the input dataframe.
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "name": ["Sally", "Mary", "John"],
  "age": [50, 40, 30],
  "qualified": [True, False, False]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

def dropCol(df):

    df.drop(columns='age',inplace=True)


dropCol(df1) #show that the "age" col is now gone from the input df


Is there a way to cordon off the function so that it cannot affect objects outside the function environment? I'd prefer my inputs to be unaffected and only have the function affect the object space via the return operator.

To be glib, if you don't want that, don't do that.  The interpreter is doing exactly what you asked for.  If you don't want to affect the original df, don't use inplace=True.  That parameter is SPECIFICALLY asking for the behavior you don't want.  Python doesn't make copies.  You are giving that function the object, not a copy of the object.

Use return df.drop(columns='age') in the function

"I'd prefer my inputs to be unaffected and only have the function affect the object space via the return operator."
That's a very good objective, but you're clearly not doing that. Let's analyze your code:
def dropCol(df): # take df as input
    df.drop(columns='age', inplace=True) # mutate it in place, return None

dropCol(df1) # pass an object to mutate

If you stick to your expected design you should use return and remove the inplace=True parameter:
def dropCol(df): # take df as input
    return df.drop(columns='age') # create a modified copy and return it

out = dropCol(df1) # pass an object, catch the transformed copy

